# Как определить формат файла

Tags: c#

По http я получаю набор байт, мне нужно каким-то образом по этому набору вычислить формат файла. Есть два метода, который должен обрабатывать pptx форматы, а другой только ppt. Другие форматы не должны быть обработаны. Как реализовать такую проверку?

У меня есть две ссылки из поисковика, которые содержат файлы, как мне определить их форма?

```
  using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
  {
     var responseRar = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync("https://pochemu4ka.ru/load/0-0-0-12031-20");
     
     var responsePpptx = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync("https://www.fit.edu/student-design-showcase/showcase-2023/mechanical-and-civil-engineering/SHOWCASE_SPRING2023_POSTER_ME_CYLINDERMATINGSYSTEM.pptx");
  }
```

Comment: Прочитать имя файла из параметра `Filename` или `FileName*` заголовка `Content-Disposition` получаемого ответа. А в нём уже смотреть расширение.

Comment: _Без кода, который получает файл, примера ссылки и знания HTTP-заголовоков, которые отправляет сервер в ответ на запрос на скачивания файла, на этот вопрос невозможно ответить конкретно._

Comment: Кстати, можно еще через Interop дернуть Power Point, открыть в нем файл и пересохранить как pptx. Тогда формат будет унифицирован. Это конечно медленная и тяжелая операция, но вам виднее. Кстати, в ответ на отправленные запросы может вернуться что угодно, то есть и не ppt, и не pptx, а например html. Вставьте ссылку в браузер, через инструменты разработчика смотрите HTTP заголовки ответа. Если серверы разные, то задача усложняется.

Comment: Тип файла может быть либо в заголовках ответа от сервера, либо в самом URL. Если и там и там пусто, то можно прочитать [Магическое число](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0#%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0)(сигнатуру) файла, несколько первых байт ответа, и по ним определить что за файл. В интернете есть много различных таблиц сигнатур ([одна из](https://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html)), по которой можем понять, что RAR например это `52 61 72 21 1A 07 01 00`.